# How do a debug an exception on python shutdown

Tags: python

When my process ends, I get output to stderr that looks like:

```
  Exception exceptions.TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <function <lambda> at 0x5507d70> ignored
```

My understanding is that this is caused by exceptions being generated during garbage collection (**del**() ?) or the weakref callback which I know is being used in this application.

What are some methods for finding out where this is coming from ?

Comment: Can you replace the lambda's with real functions?

Comment: This is way too generic. Could you post more of the output? And possibly the last few lines of code that are executed. With so little information, it's hard to tell if you're simply bumping into an unexpected mis-set variable, or on something weirder.

Comment: I'm looking for a general purpose solution for this kind of error. Really I just want to know if there is a way to get more information out of the interpreter when this happens. A full trace would be nice.

I suspect the actual problem is due to some modules getting garbage collected prior to this function getting called.

Comment: the first crucial step in getting more info, as S.Lott suggests, is forgetting the existence of `lambda` and using `def` systematically, so that all functions are named and you get a first indication of where the problem is occurring; then you dress up the calls in that function with try/except to see the name of the callee; and so on, and so forth.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing.

Unfortunately that means tracking down any use of lambda in my code or libraries I'm using.... in this case sqlalchemy was the culprit. 
@slott, if you want to make that an answer I think that's the best I'm going to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here isn't with lambdas: lambda functions *do* have debug information.

```
a = lambda: 1
print a.func_code.co_filename
print a.func_code.co_firstlineno
```

(`a.__code__` in python3.)

The problem is with the fallback exception formatting: it's not showing a stack trace, which is where this information is normally shown.

If you want to try to improve this, the problem seems to be in Python/errors.c, in PyErr_WriteUnraisable().  I don't know if there are any deeper issues making this difficult, but I suspect not.  The traceback should be in "tb" after PyErr_Fetch() is called.

Answer (score 7):

Run your Python program with the **-v option** so you can see at which point during the final stages the exception gets thrown. It helped me when I encountered the same situation; also with sqlalchemy...